# Creating table-valued function in SQL Server Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to create a new table-valued function in SQL Server Studio for my Database. I just came into control of this database and was not aware of how the previous person had added said Function. When I right click and hit new function and save it, it does not show up on the list on the left in the object explorer. Is there any way to make it show up there? Here is the image of the current ones in the object explorer.

[image]

**Edit:** Here is the script I'm attempting to add as a function

```
USE [Fusion_Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_test]
        (@deptid int)        
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
      SELECT * 
      FROM workorder
      WHERE deptid = 26;
```

Comment: Did you right-click the folder Table-valued Functions and select Refresh from the context menu? Also, did you check if you accidentally had the script on a connection to master instead of your DB? I know I've done that before!

Comment: Yeah, I've checked. The issue seems to be with it not executing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_test]
(
  @deptid INT
)        
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
      (SELECT * 
      FROM workorder
      WHERE deptid = @deptid);
```

Comment: I think you were trying to execute `ALTER FUNCTION` statement, rather then Create function. Now once you have created it, if you want to make any changes to the function definition you will have to use Alter function statement.

Comment: Yeah, that was definitely it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're saving the script, not actually executing it.  The button you're looking for is the Execute button (or perhaps just hitting the F5 key) - it will run the script that you have written.

If that script includes the [CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) statement, and your code is valid, then it will create a new function.

Once you have finished creating your function, right-click on the 'Functions' folder in Object Explorer and choose 'Refresh'.

Comment: When I try to run it I get told that I have an invalid object name.

Comment: Post the SQL script by editing your question (there's an edit button under the original post). What are you trying to name the new function?

Comment: I added it to the question.